# DB2 sql query to find non ascii characters in strings

Tags: sql, character-encoding, db2

I have a table (say `ELEMENTS`) with a VARCHAR field named `NAME` encoded in `ccsid 1144`. I need to find all the strings in the `NAME` field which contain "non ascii characters", that is characters that are in the `ccsid 1144` set of characters without the ascii ones.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to create a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CONTAINS_NON_ASCII(INSTR VARCHAR(4000))
  RETURNS CHAR(1)
  DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION CONTAINS SQL
  BEGIN ATOMIC
  DECLARE POS, LEN INT;
  IF INSTR IS NULL THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  SET (POS, LEN) = (1, LENGTH(INSTR));
  WHILE POS <= LEN DO
    IF ASCII(SUBSTR(INSTR, POS, 1)) > 128 THEN
      RETURN 'Y';
    END IF;
    SET POS = POS + 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN 'N';
END
```

And then write:

```
SELECT NAME
  FROM ELEMENTS
 WHERE CONTAINS_NON_ASCII(NAME) = 'Y'
;
```

(Disclaimer: *completely* untested.)

By the way — judging by the documentation, it seems that `VARCHAR` is a string of bytes, not of Unicode characters. (Bytes range from 0 to 0xFF; Unicode characters range from 0 to 0x10FFFD.) If you're interested in supporting Unicode, you might want to use a different data-type.

Comment: +1 thanks for the ASCII function, however the db2 manual states: *In a Unicode database, if a supplied argument is a graphic string, it is first converted to a character string before the function is executed*. As I understand that, no numbers >128 will ever be returned by ASCII, in fact the € sign is 26

Comment: @Gabber: I saw that statement, but since it seems that `VARCHAR` is always a character string, not a graphic string, I didn't think that was relevant. (In other words, I understood that statement to mean that no numbers greater than **255** will ever be returned by `ASCII`.)

Comment: From db2 manual: *VARCHAR: Varying-length character strings with a maximum length of n bytes*, no assumptions are made about the encoding, just about its length. I wouldn't have the problem otherwise, however I still find those damn € characters in my varchar fields :)

Comment: @Gabber: Is it possible that the euro sign really is being stored as `26` (since that would be an ASCII control character anyway)? Maybe instead of `ASCII(SUBSTR(INSTR, POS, 1)) > 128`, try `ASCII(SUBSTR(INSTR, POS, 1)) NOT BETWEEN 32 AND 127`? (That will detect any characters less than SP `' '` or greater than tilde `'~'`.)

Comment: Mm no, I mentioned UNICODE because I just needed to understand a possible approach and UNICODE is far more known BUT the encoding is EBCDIC 1144 and, as stated [here](http://www.longpelaexpertise.com.au/toolsCode.php) the € corresponding char code is 159. Also thinking it does a module operation is not correct because 159-127=32

Comment: Hmm, so why would `ASCII` return `26` for it? So strange. It seems like some investigation is needed; unfortunately, I can't help with that. :-/