# Python and IBM DB2: UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, db2

I'm getting this error message

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 38: ordinal not in range(128)

when I try to execute any sql query in Python, like this one:

```
>>> import ibm_db
>>> conn = ibm_db.connect("sample","root","root")
>>> ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, "select * from act")
```

I checked default encoding and it seems to be 'utf8':

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'
```

I also know about [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=ru#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/Python) thread, where people are discussing quite a similar problem. One of the advices is:

> Have you applied the required database PTFs (SI57014 and SI57015 for 7.1 and SI57146 and SI57147 for 7.2)? They are included as a distreq, so they should have been in the order with your PTFs, but won't be automatically applied.

However, I do not know what is database PTF and how to apply it. Need help.

PS. I'm using Windows 10.

**EDIT**

This is how I get my error message:

```
>>> print(ibm_db.stmt_errormsg())
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 38:    
ordinal not in range(128)
```

But when I run the same query "select * from act" in `DB2 CLP`, then it's ok.
And this is driver information, whcih I got running this code in Python:

```
if client:
    print("DRIVER_NAME: string(%d) \"%s\"" % (len(client.DRIVER_NAME), client.DRIVER_NAME))
    print("DRIVER_VER: string(%d) \"%s\"" % (len(client.DRIVER_VER), client.DRIVER_VER))
    print("DATA_SOURCE_NAME: string(%d) \"%s\"" % (len(client.DATA_SOURCE_NAME), client.DATA_SOURCE_NAME))
    print("DRIVER_ODBC_VER: string(%d) \"%s\"" % (len(client.DRIVER_ODBC_VER), client.DRIVER_ODBC_VER))
    print("ODBC_VER: string(%d) \"%s\"" % (len(client.ODBC_VER), client.ODBC_VER))
    print("ODBC_SQL_CONFORMANCE: string(%d) \"%s\"" % (len(client.ODBC_SQL_CONFORMANCE), client.ODBC_SQL_CONFORMANCE))
    print("APPL_CODEPAGE: int(%s)" % client.APPL_CODEPAGE)
    print("CONN_CODEPAGE: int(%s)" % client.CONN_CODEPAGE)
    ibm_db.close(conn)
else:
    print("Error.")
```

it prints:

```
DRIVER_NAME: string(10) "DB2CLI.DLL"
DRIVER_VER: string(10) "10.05.0007"
DATA_SOURCE_NAME: string(6) "SAMPLE"
DRIVER_ODBC_VER: string(5) "03.51"
ODBC_VER: string(10) "03.01.0000"
ODBC_SQL_CONFORMANCE: string(8) "EXTENDED"
APPL_CODEPAGE: int(1251)
CONN_CODEPAGE: int(1208)
True
```

**EDIT**

I also tried this:

```
>>> cnx = ibm_db.connect("sample","root","root")
>>> query = "select * from act"
>>> query.encode('ascii')
b'select * from act'
>>> ibm_db.exec_immediate(cnx, query)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception
>>> print(ibm_db.stmt_errormsg())
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 38: 
ordinal not in range(128)
```

As you can see, in this case I also get the very same error message.

**SUMMARY**

Below are all my attemts:

```
C:\Windows\system32>chcp
Active code page: 65001

C:\Windows\system32>python
Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ibm_db
>>> cnx = ibm_db.connect("sample","root","root")
>>> ibm_db.exec_immediate(cnx, "select * from act")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception
>>> print(ibm_db.stmt_errormsg())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 38: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> ibm_db.exec_immediate(cnx, b"select * from act")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: statement must be a string or unicode
>>> query = "select * from act"
>>> query = query.encode()
>>> ibm_db.exec_immediate(cnx, query)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: statement must be a string or unicode
>>> ibm_db.exec_immediate(cnx, "select * from act").decode('cp-1251')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception
```

Comment: what platform and version of DB2?  The PTFs and versions (7.1 & 7.2) are DB2 for IBM i.

Comment: What is your database configuration? Try a `get db cfg` when connected to the db to obtain that information.

Comment: When I do `get db cfg`, I get a long-long list of information. In this list for example I see that default database encoding is `UTF-8`. By the way, I should add that I can work with the database in the console - I can connect to a database instance and execute simple queries. The whole problem is with Python driver.

Comment: Does anybody in the world use Python 3 with DB2?

Comment: I should add that, when I run this query in DB2 prompt, then everything i ok.

Comment: The snippet of code provided looks like it should be fine.

Do you get the same error when sending an ascii encoded string as the query?

e.g.
`>>> query = "select * from act" >>> query.encode('ascii') `

Comment: Is there an error number returned and is that error a DB2 or PHP error?

Comment: @ Kerry M-R. I will check it in a minute.

Comment: @data_henrik . I've updated my question. Please, have a look.

Comment: @ Kerry M-R. I checked it. It does not help.

Comment: Just a thought, but is the problem just that you have some non-ASCII data in your table?  You could check using something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088119/db2-sql-query-to-find-non-ascii-characters-in-strings

Comment: @Peter Brittain. I've just created an empty table in `DB2 CLP`, but still I can not execute any query in Python - I get the very same error message, even though there is no data.

Comment: Given that you've already proved your query is ascii encoded, the only other  option I can see is that you're getting a non-ascii response.  Looking at the ibm_db code, it looks like it won't like that if you're running python 2...  Is that what you're running?  If so have you tried python 3?  If that's not possible, could you try using wireshark or DB2 logs to see if the request is getting to the server and, if so, what its response was?

Comment: @Peter Brittain. I'm using Python 3. I will try wireshark and DB2 logs in two days. Thanks!

Comment: Just looked a bit closer at the ibm_db code and it always decodes errors as ASCII even on Python 3.

Comment: Given that your decode problem is always at offset 38, I suspect that's the offset in the error string the DB is returning that is causing you trouble.

Comment: Thank you, Peter! Tomorrow I will try to investigate DB2 logs.

Comment: I've just checked db2diag.log. It contains a lot of data. However, when I try to execute some query in Python, it does not change this log file.

Comment: I've even changed diagnostic level to 4, but it still has no effect. I see an error message in Python, but I see nothing in logs.

Comment: That's a shame.  Well, you're definitely hitting errors in the [client C code](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/blob/master/IBM_DB/ibm_db/ibm_db.c).  At this point I think you have to wade into debugging this code and seeing what errors the native library is returning...

Comment: chr(0xc8) seems to be 'È'. Any idea where that character might come from? Which locale or languages are you using?

Comment: One of cyrillic languages. I have no idea where this character comes from.

Comment: What happens if you clone the [ibm_db git repository](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb), navigate to `IBM_DB\ibm_db`, and run `python3 tests.py`?

Comment: In this case I get this error message: `ImportError: No module named 'StringIO'`

Comment: Judging by this error message, ibm_db library is extremely outdated. Really strange

Comment: There's your problem - the library is expecting you to use Python 2.

Comment: Python 3 was released in 2008. It is really strange that 8 years were not enough for IBM developers to provide compatibility.

Comment: You're expecting a bit much of IBM :)

Comment: Have you looked where that import is?  It's in tests.py!  This file is not written for Python 3, but the underlying code is.  You can see the [check-in for when they ported it in 2012](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/commit/795c794ec520571a5b7a2521818d43ba8f4999c4)

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is an incompatibility between your client code (ibm_db) and the DB2 server.  As you can see in the [client code](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/blob/master/IBM_DB/ibm_db/ibm_db.c) the logic for your query is basically:

1. Extract and check the parameters passed in (lines 4873 to 4918).
2. Allocate native objects for the query (up to 4954).
3. Do the query and decode the results (the rest of the function).

Based on our investigations so far, you know that the data you're passing in for the query is well-formed (and so it is not step 1).  Looking at the error paths in step 2, you'd see simple error messages explaining these failures.  You're therefore failing in step 3.

You are getting an empty Exception raised on the query and when you try to get the details of the error you get another Unicode decoding Exception.  This looks like either a bug in ibm_db or a configuration error that means your DB2 installation is not compatible.  So how can we find out which...?

As flagged elsewhere, the issue is fundamentally to do with codepages.  All the ibm_db code basically interprets strings as ASCII (by converting them with `StringOBJ_FromASCII` which maps down to calls into Python APIs that insist on receiving ASCII chars - and will throw unicode exceptions if not).

Based on your diags, you could try to prove/disprove this problem, by installing/configuring both your systems (client and DB2 server) to use US English.  This should get you past the codepage incompatibility to find the real error here.

If the query is really going out over the network, you might just get a network trace that shows the response coming back from the server.  However, based on the fact that you saw nothing in the logs, I'm not convinced this will bear any fruit.

Failing that you need to patch the ibm_db code to handle non-ASCII content - either by raising a bug report with the maintainer or trying it yourself (if you know how to build and debug C extensions).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. But now it seems like ibm_db library is simply not compatible with Python 3. Have you ever tried to connect to DB2 from Python 3 code?

Comment: I've not personally used it, but the ibm_db library is compatible with Python 3.  This is clearly documented in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ibm_db/ and tallies with the fact that the library is written for Python 2 and 3.  Your issue is not Python 3.  I suspect that the maintainers however, have only ever used it on a US English system.

Comment: On final thought...  You might be better off raising an [issue](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues) against the github project.

Comment: Thanks, Peter! I will probably do it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the DB2 server is returned CP-1251 (also known as Windows-1251) text (as evidenced by `APPL_CODEPAGE: int(1251)`) in your config output. Python (specifically, the interactive Python REPL) is expecting either UTF-8 or ASCII output, so this causes issues.

The solution is to do:

```
ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, "select * from act").decode('cp-1251')
```

Additionally, you need to make sure that your terminal's text encoding is set to UTF-8. Details on changing that setting will depend on the specific terminal that you are using. Since you have said you are using `cmd`, the appropriate command is `chcp 65001`.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it in a minute!

Comment: I wish it worked, but it is not working. When I run `ibm_db.exec_immediate(cnx, b"select * from act")` I get this error message: `Exception: statement must be a string or unicode`

Comment: Doing `query = query.encode()` and then "passing the query string to ibm_db.exec_immediate" also does not work. And the error message once again is `Exception: statement must be a string or unicode`

Comment: Try `ibm_db.exec_immediate(cnx, "select * from act").decode('cp-1251')`.

Comment: In this case once again I get me very first error message `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 38: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: What terminal are you using, and what is the terminal's text encoding set to?

Comment: I'm using Windows `cmd` tool. As for text encoding, I'm not sure how to check it.

Comment: `chcp` in `cmd` returns `866`. So, like you said, it is not utf8. I will try to change it now.

Comment: Please, have a look at my question. I updated it. I did almost everything, but nothing helps.

Comment: To me it looks like `ibm_db` bug. I posted my question at `IBM` site, but there is almost no activity and I did not get any advice.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of case, using an utf8 environment, with a stuff that  requires a ascii one; i use the decode method.

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc8
```

Allright, it's normal, this is not ascii but utf8 string: you should decode it with utf8 encoding.

```
...  
query.decode('utf8')  
ibm_db.exec_immediate(cnx, query)
```

After that you may need to re-encode the results to write or print them.

Comment: I will check it in a minute.

Comment: It's not working. `query.decode('utf8') ` results into `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`