# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128) While reading DATA FROM DB2 Table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, db2

getting the error while reading data from DB2 table using PYTHON 3.x.

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Can you try to read file with `encoding='utf-8'` parameter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python and IBM DB2: UnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395235/python-and-ibm-db2-unicodedecodeerror)

Comment: no . I did not find anything for python 3.x. Can you please help with an answer

Comment: EDIT your question to add *all* environment and version details. What's your Db2-server platform and version ? What's your database-code page and territory ? What operating-system runs Python 3.x? Which Db2-client are you using and what is its version?  What's the version of the ibm_db module ?  What's the column-datatype being fetched? Show your *code*, or make a reproducible example.

Comment: It may be recommended to review: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649512/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe2-in-position-13-ordinal

Answer (score 0):

By default, both Python and your ODBC driver are looking at your locale settings in Linux to determine your default encoding.

First, set your locale settings as follows:

```
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

Second, instead of using string literals in your SQL queries, use parameters:

for example, change

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO table (data) VALUES ('non-ascii stuff')"
```

to

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO table (data) VALUES (?)", ['non-ascii stuff'])
```